# how to sort alphanumeric column in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, sorting, zend-framework2

I need to sort a column in ascending order and that column has alphanumeric values. How to sort the alphanumeric column in ascending order using Zend Framework 2?

My query is like this:

```
$select->order(array(
    'customer_plant.customer_plant', 
    'CASE WHEN supplier.supplier_code > A 
     THEN lpad(supplier.supplier_code, 40, 0) 
     ELSE supplier.supplier_code END  ASC',
    'part.part'
));
```

When I run it, it shows an error:

> column "CASE" does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...) ORDER BY "customer_plant"."customer_plant" ASC, "CASE" ASC...

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? Right now it doesn't look like you have bothered to do any research into the problem on your own. Without additional details, it's hard to know what you are trying to do. Does anything [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html) look helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$select` is an instance of `Zend\Db\Sql\Select`, try this:

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;

$select->order'customer_plant.customer_plant')
       ->order(new Expression('CASE WHEN supplier.supplier_code > A 
                THEN lpad(supplier.supplier_code, 40, 0) 
                ELSE supplier.supplier_code END ASC'))
       ->order('part.part');
```